# How to parse Response from WebService call in Play 2.3.x

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services, playframework

Background : I'm calling backend WebServices from `Play controller` and sending the `Response` (in JSON format) to **AngularJS** module wrapped in `play.mvc.Result`. This integration works seamlessly.

Problem Statement : Now I want to parse the `Response` and use it for some business logic; but `play.mvc.Result` class has only one method which is `toScala()`. **How do I get the body of `play.mvc.Result`**.
Can I use `play.libs.F.Promise` to get my job done?

Below is the Generalized code which takes JSON request body and Service URL as parameter and returns the `play.mvc.Result`.

```
WSRequestHolder requestHolder = WS.url("https://application.url/ws/endpoint")
                .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
final Promise<String> promise = requestHolder.post(jsonRequest)
            .map(new Function<WS.Response, String>() {
                @Override
                public String apply(final Response a) throws Throwable {
                    //Do i need to Parse from here???
                    return a.getBody();
                }
            });

return Results.async(promise.map(new Function<String, Result>() {
    @Override
    public Result apply(final String a) throws Throwable {
        if(STR_UNAUTHORIZED.equals(a)){
            return Results.redirect(controllers.routes.Authentication.login("",""));
        }
        return Results.ok(a);
    }
}));
```

So is there a way to extract the `Response` body from `play.mvc.Result` or is there any alternate way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code would Parse the response from WebService call in synchronized way:

```
WSRequestHolder requestHolder = WS.url("https://application.url/ws/endpoint")
            .setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
final Promise<WS.Response> promise = requestHolder.get();
Response myResponse=promise.get(50000); 
// This code returns the Parsed response in form of String
return myResponse.getBody();
```